# View Controller is not deinitialized when expected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, memory

I am trying to understand the difference between doing a task in **serial async DispatchQueue** and then doing the same task in a **method/function** by referencing it through a **weak self** from the same **DispatchQueue**.

**Code - 1**

An asyncAfter block is executed after 1.5 seconds while **task()** is processing which dismisses the view controller but **deinit()** is only called after **task()** in finished.

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5, execute: {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", qos: .default)

        queue.async {[weak self] in
            self?.task()
        }
    }

    private func task() {
        print("start")
        for i in 0...10000000 {
            if i%500 == 0 {

            }
        }
        print("stop")
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

Console output = start stop deinit

**Code - 2**

In this case **deinit()** is called as expected just after the view controller is dismissed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5, execute: {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    })

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", qos: .default)

    queue.async {[weak self] in
        print("start")
        for i in 0...10000000 {
            if i%500 == 0 {

            }
        }
        print("stop")
    }
}

deinit {
    print("deinit")
}
```

Console output = start deinit stop

Can somebody please explain why is there a difference between the two?

Comment: please try and share the output of  `print(Thread.current)` in `task()` function

Comment: @emrcftci output for `print(Thread.current)` inside `task()` is `<NSThread: 0x60000092d480>{number = 4, name = (null)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although both closures use `weak self`, the first invokes a function on the view controller.  This causes the view controller to be retained until that function returns.

If it wasn't then the view controller would be released while the function was still executing, which would be a Bad Thing

In the second closure, there is no reference to `self` so the closure is simply retained by the dispatch queue.

Comment: Why would the view controller be retained if the only thing referencing the method is a weak reference and doesn't "strongly" hold it?

Comment: There is an implicit strong reference to `self` to prevent the object being released while its code is executing. If there wasn’t then there would be a crash as the function was torn down while it was running